# SQL Server INSERT Command doesn't insert data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, insert

I want to insert the content of some textboxes into a SQL Server database.

This is the code I use:

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
myConn.Open();

SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO invmgmt.Products (product_id, product_name, product_price, possible_discount, product_in_stock) VALUES ('" + Convert.ToInt32(tbAddProdID.Text) + "','" + tbAddProdName.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(tbAddProdPrice.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(tbAddPblDiscount.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(tbAddInStock.Text) + "')");

myConn.Close();
```

If I execute that, nothing happens to the database, does anyone know what to do? I've tried some other `Insert` commands, but nothing wants to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to associate a connection with your command then **execute** your query:

```
InsertCommand.Connection = conn;
InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Few other things:

- **Do not** use string concatenation to create SQL Query. Use parameters with your query. See: [SqlCommand.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) otherwise you are prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- Enclose your connection and command object in [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.

Comment: +1 for using parameters. String concatenation is wide open to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Answer (score 1):

add the connection to your command and execute it:

```
 SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO invmgmt.Products (product_id, product_name, product_price, possible_discount, product_in_stock) VALUES ('" + Convert.ToInt32(tbAddProdID.Text) + "','" + tbAddProdName.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(tbAddProdPrice.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(tbAddPblDiscount.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(tbAddInStock.Text) + "')",myConn);

 InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you, I got 2 faults. First was not to write InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); Secound was to forget the secound parameter of the SQLCommand

Answer (score 1):

You are missing:

```
InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

after opening connection try code below:

```
string query = ..........;
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConn.Close();
```

Note: type your query instead of dots.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I forgot the second parameter of the SqlCommand.

Comment: no problem, you can accept the answer in order to help others who has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

**ExecuteNonQuery()** return the number of rows affected, so its better to check the return to handle error condition

Int32 ret = sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (ret <= 0)
{
`enter code here`
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the query and close your connection after this as shown below

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
myConn.Open();

string sql ="YOUR QUERY...";
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(myConnection);
myConn.Open();
SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql,myConn);
InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
myConn.Close();
```

or if you want to check if query is executed or not do this instead.

```
if(InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()>0){ //some message or function }
```

the returned value are the number of rows affected by the statement.